# Find the square submatrix with the highest sum of boundary elements

Tags: c

Consider a 2D matrix of numbers from 0 to 9 with variable width and height. Find the square submatrix with the highest sum of boundary elements.

Input :

Input width and height of matrix: 6 8

Input Matrix with numbers from 0 to 9:

2 0 6 1 2 5 
1 0 5 0 1 3 
3 0 1 2 4 1 
0 1 3 1 1 9 
4 1 0 8 5 2 
0 1 0 1 2 3
6 5 3 1 0 2
0 0 1 6 0 4 
Input maximum width of square submatrix (for square submatrix height and width are same) : 3

Output :

As sum of highlighted submatrix is maximum (calcute sum of boundary elements only 2,4,1,9,2,5,8,1),

2 0 6 1 2 5 
1 0 5 0 1 3 
3 0 1 2 4 1 
0 1 3 1 1 9 
4 1 0 8 5 2 
0 1 0 1 2 3
6 5 3 1 0 2
0 0 1 6 0 4 
Output should be :

2 4 1
 1 1 9
 8 5 2

please explain this with pseudo code....

Comment: You need to do research to devise an algorithm that solves your problem. That is your work.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define R 8
#define C 6

// matrix of size R x C
void printMaxSumSub(int mat[R][C], int k)
{
    if (k > C) return;

    int stripSum[R][C];

// Go column by column
for (int j=0; j<C; j++)
{

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
        sum += mat[i][j];
    stripSum[0][j] = sum;

    //  sum of remaining rectangles
    for (int i=1; i<R-k+1; i++)
    {
        sum += (mat[i+k-1][j] - mat[i-1][j]);
        stripSum[i][j] = sum;
    }
}

// max_sum stores maximum sum 

int max_sum = INT_MIN, *pos = NULL;

for (int i=0; i<R-k+1; i++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j<k; j++)
        sum += stripSum[i][j];
    if (sum > max_sum)
    {
        max_sum = sum;
        pos = &(mat[i][0]);
    }

    for (int j=1; j<R-k+1; j++)
    {
        sum += (stripSum[i][j+k-1] - stripSum[i][j-1]);

        if (sum > max_sum)
        {
            max_sum = sum;
            pos = &(mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<k; j++)
        cout << *(pos + i*C + j) << " ";
    cout << endl;
    }
}

//  function
int main()
{
    int mat[R][C] = {{2, 0 ,6 ,1 ,2, 5},    
    {1, 0, 5, 0 ,1, 3}, 
    {3 ,0, 1 ,2 ,4 ,1}, 
    {0 ,1, 3, 1, 1, 9}, 
    {4 ,1, 0 ,8 ,5 ,2}, 
    {0 ,1, 0, 1 ,2 ,3},
    {6 ,5 ,3 ,1 ,0, 2},
    {0 ,0, 1, 6, 0, 4}  
    };
    int k = 3;

cout << "the  sum  of 3 x 3 matrix is\n";
printMaxSumSub(mat, k);

    return 0;
}


//Output

the  sum  of 3 x 3 matrix is                                                                                                     
2 4 1                                                                                                                            
1 1 9                                                                                                                            
8 5 2
```

Comment: In reference to {cout << *(pos + i*C + j) << " ";} this line......Actually I am not well aware with pointer can you give any alternative to this?

Comment: OK , But for this result nothing any alternative solution, So i thing you need to understand Pointer.